# Python selenium shows exception

Tags: javascript, python, css, python-3.x, selenium

I am getting an exception while trying to open a new link. I have written python script and I expected it will open new link whenever it meets certain condition but while it meet condition it shows alert popup(while entering my credential, it shows exception) and I don't know how to fix it. Currently I am working on Firefox browser and I also checked previous questions related to this issue, where their issue got fixed by changing the browser from Firefox to IE, but in my case I can't use IE since my base link will not open(support) in IE. Is there any way to fix this one?

Here is my code:

```
import time
from datetime import datetime
from selenium import webdriver

try:

    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="C:\\Users\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\Lib\\site-packages\\selenium\\webdriver\\firefox\\geckodriver.exe")
    driver.get('https://base_link')

    my_id = driver.find_element_by_name('j_username')
    my_id.send_keys('1895')

    password = driver.find_element_by_name('j_password')
    password.send_keys('1895')

    ext = driver.find_element_by_name('extension_login_user')
    ext.send_keys('4081111895')

    sign_in_button = driver.find_element_by_id('signin-button')
    sign_in_button.click()

    time.sleep(30)

    driver.set_window_size(1024, 768)
    driver.maximize_window()

    ticket_opened = False
    window = 0
    while True:
        if driver.find_element_by_id('state-text').text == 'Not Ready - GMC Work':
            time.sleep(1)

            if driver.find_element_by_id('state-text').text == "Not Ready - Break":
                if ticket_opened is False:
                    driver.execute_script("$(window.open('child_link'))")
                    driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[window])
                    window += 1
                    continue
                else:
                    ticket_opened = False
            else:
                continue
        else:
            continue

except Exception as e:
    print('Exception Occurred: ' + str(e))
    print('Time and Date: ' + str(datetime.now())[0:19])
```

Here I am getting the exception (output):

```
Exception Occurred: Alert Text: None
Message: 

Time and Date: 2017-10-19 04:13:39
```

Kindly help me to fix out this one using python selenium. If we can't fix this one, then kindly suggest me some other tool/way to fix this one.

Comment: Your approach to exception handling is not helping you here.  There could be hundreds of possible errors, all caught by a single `except` that prints out no useful diagnostic information.  Try printing a traceback inside the except block to see which line is raising the exception (import traceback; traceback.print_exc()).

Comment: Either that or just remove the try/except block until you know what you're looking for. Dunno if it's an error with copying, but `if "driver.find_element_by_id('state-text').text == "Not Ready - Break":` has an incorrect speech mark at the start.

Comment: driver.execute_script("$(window.open('child_link'))") seems will not to open the link, but open new window/dialog.  because window.open() use to open dialog/window.  Are you sure you use the right way to open the link?

Comment: Whenever it meets condition i have to ooen new tab. That's why i used (window.open(child_link)). Moreover its shows exception even if i try to open child link manually in my webdriver .